# typescript how to define the response when it extends a blind input

Tags: typescript

something.ts

```
export const thing = (input: Record<any, any>) => {
  input.updatedAt = new Date();
  return input;
};
```

myfile.ts

```
import {thing} from '../lib/thing'

class Mycache {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const a = thing(Mycache);
console.log(a.updatedAt)
```

Is it possible to type the response of the function `thing` so as it can extend a blind input?

Comment: 2 cents: you'd probably want to refactor the function if possible. If `updatedAt` is not defined in the input, the blackbox mutation is risky. Judging from your use case, can't you just define `Mycache` as having a property `updatedAt`, initially set to `undefined` or `null` depending on your preference?

Comment: ^ After all, your input is not that blind - you expect an object that can be updated, so after changing the interface of the input, you can safely constrain the input to be a record + `{ 
updatedAt: Date }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types). Type `T` can extend anything that extends object, e.g. `Record<...>`.

```js
export const thing = <T extends Record<any, any>>(input: T): T & { updatedAt: Date } => {
    ...
};
```

Comment: But the shape of input is always unknown to thing

Comment: yea i was there earlier as i thought that made sense but ts disagrees

```TS2339: Property 'updatedAt' does not exist on type 'T'.```

Comment: You will have to force type conversion on input using `input as T & { updatedAt: Date }`. You could make a new variable called `newInput` or `_input` and force type conversion on it.